# How can I get the fivestar module to submit the page url to the database?

Tags: views, rating

I know the module stores the entity_id of the "page"/node and I can translate the enity_id's (node id's) to url paths like so, so I can display them in a view:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  // Translate the enity_id's to url paths. 
  $results = $view->result;
  foreach ($results as $item =>  $data) {
    $view->result[$item]->votingapi_vote_entity_id = url('node/' . $data->votingapi_vote_entity_id);
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I add a filter to my view so that I can filter the content by url path it still requires to me add an actual entity_id in the filter field (if this makes sense). 
I want to be able to extend the fivestar vote submission so that it also submits the node path. This will allow me to quickly add a filter to my view and filter the content by url path. I'm currently struggling with this and nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this:

- create a hidden field to include the path of the current node
- using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), set an event after node save to populate that field with the nodes path
- filter in views based on that field

I'm not certain if Rules will be able to pick up the new path, but I think it would trigger far enough into the process that the node path would be set.

Comment: I have a hidden field that sores the url path. But was hoping that I wouldn't need another module to do this?

Comment: it should filter by that field then without issue. I think perhaps there is a setting problem in your filter if you have to enter the entity_id to filter by a different field.